# Как сделать резиновый блок с внутренней прокруткой

Tags: css, css3

У меня есть 2 вложенных div.

```
.partners-filters-search-dd{
  position: absolute;
  width:216px;
  min-height: 110px;
  background:#fff;
  border: 2px #dce1e4 solid;
  margin-top:1px;
  margin-left:-2px;
  z-index: 6;
  display: none;
  max-height: 550px;
}

.partners-filters-search-dd-container{
  width:181px;
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: -o-calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

partners-filters-search-dd является родителем для partners-filters-search-dd-container

У контейнеров фиксированная ширина, а вот высота должна быть в пределах 110 пикс до 550. Если наполнение элементами в контейнере partners-filters-search-dd-container привышает высоту, то должна быть вертикальная прокрутка.

Код выше не верный. Можете подправить что бы добиться нужного мне результата?

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, такое впечатление, что в Вашем коде css просто какой-то генератор случайных стилей поработал=). Особенно `display: none`... В общем, если ограничить задачу этими двумя блоками, достаточно задать `min-height`, `max-height` и поставить `overflow-y: auto;`

```css
div.partners-filters-search-dd-container {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

div.partners-filters-search-dd {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  min-height: 110px;
  max-height: 550px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners-filters-search-dd-container">
  <div class="partners-filters-search-dd">
    <p>Мало текста</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="partners-filters-search-dd-container">
  <div class="partners-filters-search-dd">
    <p>partners-filters-search-dd является родителем для partners-filters-search-dd-container</p>

    <p>У контейнеров фиксированная ширина, а вот высота должна быть в пределах 110 пикс до 550. Если наполнение элементами в контейнере partners-filters-search-dd-container привышает высоту, то должна быть вертикальная прокрутка.</p>

    <p>Код выше не верный. Можете подправить что бы добиться нужного мне результата?</p>
    <p>partners-filters-search-dd является родителем для partners-filters-search-dd-container</p>

    <p>У контейнеров фиксированная ширина, а вот высота должна быть в пределах 110 пикс до 550. Если наполнение элементами в контейнере partners-filters-search-dd-container привышает высоту, то должна быть вертикальная прокрутка.</p>
    <p>partners-filters-search-dd является родителем для partners-filters-search-dd-container</p>

    <p>У контейнеров фиксированная ширина, а вот высота должна быть в пределах 110 пикс до 550. Если наполнение элементами в контейнере partners-filters-search-dd-container привышает высоту, то должна быть вертикальная прокрутка.</p>

    <p>Код выше не верный. Можете подправить что бы добиться нужного мне результата?</p>
    <p>partners-filters-search-dd является родителем для partners-filters-search-dd-container</p>

    <p>У контейнеров фиксированная ширина, а вот высота должна быть в пределах 110 пикс до 550. Если наполнение элементами в контейнере partners-filters-search-dd-container привышает высоту, то должна быть вертикальная прокрутка.</p>

    <p>Код выше не верный. Можете подправить что бы добиться нужного мне результата?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.partners-filters-search-dd{
}

.partners-filters-search-dd-container{
width: 100%;
min-height: 110px;
height: auto;
max-height: 550px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="partners-filters-search-dd">
<div class="partners-filters-search-dd-container">
<p>Lorem</p>
</div>
<div class="partners-filters-search-dd-container">
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
</div>
<div class="partners-filters-search-dd-container">
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
</div>
</div>
```